# Is it a touchdown if the receiver puts a knee out of bounds before the second foot in bounds?

Tags: rules, american-football

Is this considered a touchdown - attempting a catch, the receiver gets one foot touched down in bounds, then the knee touches the ground out of bounds, then the second foot touches in bounds?

Answer (score 4):

In the NFL then, no, both feet always need to touch in bounds while the receiver has possession. Once any part of the body touches out of bounds the play is immediately dead so anything that happens after that instant doesn’t matter.

[Section 2, Article 7: Player Possession](https://operations.nfl.com/media/4693/2020-nfl-rulebook.pdf)

Now for a reception in the NCAA the point is irrelevant as the rule is you only need to establish one foot in bounds while maintaining possession.

[Section 4, Article 3: Catch, Interception, Recovery](http://www.ncaapublications.com/productdownloads/FR20.pdf)

Comment: FYI the respective rules for both leagues apply to ANY catch. Not just a catch in the endzone

Comment: Hi - welcome to the site!  This answer is correct, but it would be better by including references to the NFL rulebook (or other similar sources).